# which app domain can I use for Facebook API

Tags: django, facebook

I'm developing Django application and want to use Facebook API.
I've registered the application at Facebook.

And I want to test authentication of Facebook API by local developing environment before deploy at production server.
I always start Django on local developing environment by
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
After that I can access my browser at http://192.168.7.38:8000/ for example.

But I can't register the testApp at Facebook.
On settings I must register App Domains and Site URL.
I registered
App Domains : 192.168.7.38
Site URL : http://192.168.7.38:8000/

But when I registered App Domains , error occured.
'App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: 192.168.7.38'

What can I register App Domains?
Sorry for my poor English.Thank you.

Comment: from memory you must use https for all facebook apps. so you need an SSL cert.

Comment: I think you can use 'https://localhost:8000'

Comment: Thank you very much.
But when I use 'localhost:8000', error occured.
'Top-level domains are not allowed'
What can I do?

Comment: Just set up a local domain on your dev system, f.e. via the hosts file - `myapp.local` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe.
I set up /etc/hosts   '127.0.0.1       myapp.local'.
But when I set up 'myapp.local' for App Domain at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ settings,error occured again ''App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. ".
Should I change 'Site URL'?  It is 'http://192.168.7.38:8000/'  ,now. 
If I should change it,how?

Comment: _"Should I change 'Site URL'?"_ - Of course you need to make them match. How - well what did you think setting up that local domain name was good for? `http://myapp.local:8000/` And if that still doesn't work, it might be because of the non-standard port, Facebook might be picky about that as well; if so, set up your dev server to listen to port 80, and use `http://myapp.local/`

Comment: Thank you CBroe. http://myapp.local:8000/ and http://myapp.local/ works without problems.
And I can register at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ App Domains:'myapp.local' and 'http://myapp.local:8000/'. But when I access Facebook authentication page in my site,the error occured again. 'Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.' 
I can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: I can resolved.
If my production server's URL is http://www.myapp.com,
sudo vim etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 myapp.com

So I can access this site http://myapp.com:8000/.

At https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ , 
App Domains:myapp.com
Site URL:http://myapp.com:8000/

So authentication works.